# How to animate svg element as soon as it appears on screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, svg

I can't seem to figure out how to integrate the javascript file to animate the svg element as soon as it appears on screen.

I found a javascript example on stackoverflow but for some reason it is not working.

HTML

```
<section class="line-animation">
   <svg version="1.1" class="yellow-line" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"....etc</svg
</section>
```

CSS

```
.yellow-line {
   stroke-dasharray: 1137.627;
   animation: dash 3s ease-in;
   width: 600px;
   margin-top: -78px;
}

   @keyframes dash {
      from {
         stroke-dashoffset: 1137.627;
   }
   to {
         stroke-dashoffset: 0;
   } 
  }
```

Javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.yellow-line').viewportChecker({
classToAdd: 'visible',

offset: 100,

repeat: false,

callbackFunction: function(elem, action){}
});
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: @Rohit "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    lineanimation.js:1"

Comment: where is viewportChecker() defined? Are you using any third party js library?

Comment: @Rohit No, I copied and pasted the code above in a new javascript file and linked it to the html file.